# What is the type of data-testid in React and TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to add `data-testid` as prop to a component and I am unsure what its type could be. Below is my code:

```
<ChildComponent
    dataTestId="someid"
/>

export type ChildComponentProps = {

    dataTestId?: any; // what should be the type here instead of any
    Pick<
        React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>,
            'id' | 'checked' | 'name'
    >;
}

const ChildComponent: FC<ChildComponentProps> = ({
    dataTestId,
    ...props
}) => (
    <Switch {...props}>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-testid={dataTestId}
        />
    </Switch>
)
```

What should be the type for `dataTestId` in this case?

Comment: What type are you passing with `dataTestId="someid"`?

Comment: string okay got it

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, `string` is the answer, **but** you can improve your typing by maintaining the original `data-testid` as the property with the dash in between when you use your ChildComponent in the parent.

```
// Usage in the parent component, see that we keep the same dashed property
<ChildComponent data-testid="someid"/>


// Then the child component
interface ChildComponentProps 
  extends Pick<React.InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, 'id' | 'checked' | 'name'> = {
  'data-testid'?: string;
}

export const ChildComponent: FC<ChildComponentProps> = ({
  'data-testid': dataTestId,
  ...props
}) => (
  <Switch {...props}>
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      data-testid={dataTestId}
    />
  </Switch>
)
```